# Multidimensional array via ajax to php turns into null via json_decode

Tags: php, javascript, null, json

I have gathered data with jQuery, putten it into a multidimensional array, used `JSON.stringify` on it and passed it to PHP by use of AJAX, for some reason json_decode keeps on giving me a `Syntax error, malformed JSON` error.

Heres the JSON that gets passed on to the PHP

```
[\"foo\",\"foobar did the baz\",[[\"bar\",\"kg\",\"200\"],[\"baz\",\"l\",\"1337\"]]]
```

The weird thing is that i use JSON.stringify on the multidimensional array in JS. Heres how i put it together

```
var dataz = [];
var arrayContainingAll = [];

$("li", "#ingredientlist").each(function() {
    var tempArray = [];
    tempArray.push($(".ingredientname", this).text());
    tempArray.push($(".unittext", this).text());
    tempArray.push($(".amounttext", this).text());
    arrayContainingAll.push(tempArray);
});

dataz.push($("h1").text());
dataz.push($("#method").val());
dataz.push(arrayContainingAll);
var json = JSON.stringify(dataz);
```

How can i make PHP parse the multidimensional array correctly?
I have fixed it by passing on 3 different stringified arrays, but its more the curiosity of why a multidimensional array fails

The PHP to show what happens is: `var_dump(json_decode($_POST['ingredients']));`

because it appearantly is important to show how i post the data, heres the JS to do the ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/savenewrecipe.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'ingredients=' + json + "&name=" + $("h1").text() + "&method=" + $("#method").val(),
    success: function(result) {
        if (result.ok == true) {
            // @todo remove this for debugging purposes
            //document.location.href = '/recipe/' + result.id;
        }
        else {
            showError("Noget gik galt!", 2000);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: where do u post it to php in ur js??

Comment: did you pass it through stripslashes() ?

Comment: no, look in the code - i simply put it through json_decode

Comment: also what does ur php think is in `$_POST[ingredients']` ?

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky please post the stripslashes text as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your server uses magic quotes, you'll need to remove them:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  $_POST['ingredients'] = stripslashes($_POST['ingredients']);
}
```

Comment: i just read the comment section i think you beat me to the answer =) +1